# How secure is it to log into Github on a server?

Tags: git, security, github, server

I have been given access to a remote (Ubuntu) server that will be used to run some code. I am not the only one making use of the server and was wondering how secure it is for me to clone a git repo (and hence, having to log in via Github).

To be clear, I am only concerned about the security of my login credentials to Github. The fact that the repo is on the server and visible by other people is no issue. I am just curious of how the log in happens to git, and if any of that traffic/credentials are being stored by the server, or can be monitored by other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anybody who has administrative access to the server (e.g. anybody who has the `root` password) can observe everything you do, including all your keystrokes (e.g. passwords), and access everything you store (e.g. your private keys).

Anybody who has physical access to the server (including, but not limited to, the owner of the server, but also the cleaning lady) can elevate their privileges to `root`, so we end up at case #1 again.

The least bad solution (which is however not saying much) I see is to set up SSH Agent forwarding on the server, so that the Agent on the server only forwards the authentication request to your personal computer, and the actual authentication happens with the Agent on your personal computer.

Comment: [SSH Agent forwarding is also vulnerable to root](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#sec). I'd still consider it the best option.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have said "least bad".